# Can't find external package when building docker image from Java app

Tags: java, docker, maven, apache-poi

I can't seem to build an image from my java app. The app runs fine.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:18-oracle
WORKDIR /src/main/java
COPY /src/main/java/Main.java .
RUN javac Main.java
CMD ["java", "Main"]
```

I get the following errors:

```
#10 [6/6] RUN javac Main.java
#10 sha256:c98f9fd10afe295d225fd7f29fa5935c9ee4488ff64cd708cb758a0dce4b638d
#10 2.096 Main.java:7: error: package org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf does not exist
#10 2.096 import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
#10 2.096                                         ^
#10 2.099 Main.java:8: error: package org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf does not exist
#10 2.099 import org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
#10 2.099                                         ^
#10 2.102 Main.java:9: error: package org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel does not exist
#10 2.102 import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
#10 2.102                                     ^
#10 2.249 Main.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
#10 2.249             XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);
#10 2.249             ^
#10 2.249   symbol:   class XWPFDocument
#10 2.249   location: class Main
#10 2.251 Main.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
#10 2.252             XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);
#10 2.252                                         ^
#10 2.252   symbol:   class XWPFDocument
#10 2.252   location: class Main
#10 2.254 Main.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
#10 2.254             PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
#10 2.254             ^
#10 2.254   symbol:   class PdfOptions
#10 2.254   location: class Main
#10 2.256 Main.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
#10 2.256             PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
#10 2.256                                  ^
#10 2.256   symbol:   variable PdfOptions
#10 2.256   location: class Main
#10 2.259 Main.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
#10 2.259             PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
#10 2.259             ^
#10 2.259   symbol:   variable PdfConverter
#10 2.259   location: class Main
#10 2.275 8 errors
#10 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c javac Main.java]: exit code: 1
------
 > [6/6] RUN javac Main.java:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c javac Main.java]: exit code: 1
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I am assuming I need to somehow import the Apache POI dependency during build.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How are you fetching the dependencies? Why are you building by hand with `javac` rather than using something like Gradle or Maven?

Comment: "The app runs fine.": How are you calling the app when it runs fine?